# High temperatures after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, power-management

I upgraded my Lenovo T590 to Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu 18.04. Since the upgrade, I've noticed that the temperatures are higher than before when the laptop is connected into AC power.

Additionally, I've observed that the PowerMode settings are not functioning correctly. The power-saver mode works fine, but the performance mode makes the pc slower than the balanced mode. In the balanced mode, the temperatures reach 98°C to 100°C, while in performance mode, they stay around 50°C to 70°C, even when performing the same tasks. I've searched through various forums, but I couldn't find anyone else experiencing the same problem.

I attempted to resolve the issue by disabling TLP, which I had installed initially, thinking that its configuration was the problem but the problem persists.